# is it possible to have a sharepoint workflow that can dynamically switch content types?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, content-type, designer-workflow

I have a document library that contains 5 content types ( different word documents that have quickparts in them )
I have another list that has some customer information.
I want to start my workflow from this customer list and get it to populate my content types and write the data into my document library.

I have tried making a workflow that does this:

1. I created 5 initiation form parameters in a dropdown
2. I have an if sentence that looks what parameter has been selected and then sets that value to a content type id
3. I create a list element in my library with path and name

My problem is that the ID for content type CANNOT be taken out of the create so every document that gets created is the "default" one.

Is there a way to change this?

Can I delete the ID for content type from the create inside the workflow and then set my own content instead?